# @Data annotion not working to set the value in Java

Tags: java, lombok

I have this POJO class:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class FulfillmentOrder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name="orderNbr")
    Integer orderNbr;

    public Integer setOrderNumbr(Integer orderNbr) {
        this.orderNbr=orderNbr;
        return orderNbr;
    }
}
```

I am trying to set the value of `orderNbr` from a different class.

```
FulfillmentOrder fo= new FulfillmentOrder();
Integer orderNum = 
  fo.setOrderNumbr(89898989);
```

I am trying to update the value of `orderNbr` in my XML output to 89898 and I want to do it using @Data.

But when I am doing `fo.setOrderNbr(89898989)`I am getting a compile time error as Error:(56, 132) java: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer, since lombok returns void.

Any way of `fo.setOrderNbr(89898989) to update the value?

Comment: this is the basics of Java nothing to do with Lombok. Even basics of programming - you cant operate on an object without allocating memory to it first. So you need to change your first line to instantiate `FulfillmentOrder` with `FulfillmentOrder fo = new FulfillmentOrder()`.

Comment: @JAsgarov sorry I forgot to add that, even after adding that, the problem is same.

Comment: seems like Lombok generated setter (with return type void) is clashing with your custom setter (with return type Integer). You have to choose one, or change name of yours to not be identical

Comment: @JAsgarov my purpose is to set the orderNbr to be 89898989, because later I am converting to xml object. Is there a way of doing it with lombok annotation?

Comment: In most cases setters return instance of current object(like in a builder) or void. There is little/no point in returning value passed inside, as it should remain immutable. So Maybe remove custom setters and let lombok create them.

Comment: @Beri thanks for your comment, can you please provide a code snippet if I need to set the value of orderNum to 89898989 without using setOrderNbr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your class effectively has two methods with the same signature. Signature of a method is its name + parameters. So in your case `setOrderNbr(Integer orderNbr)`. Return type is not included in the signature.

As explained in Javadoc it is a compile time error to have methods with identical signature in the same class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2

For you to allow Lombok to do the work - you need to delete your method `setOrderNbr(Integer orderNbr)` and call the Lombok generated setter that comes from `@Data`. It will have the same name but no return type in accordance with usual coding practices.

If you insist on having a setter with a return type you will have to define it yourself but it has to have a different signature - in your case a different name to not clash with the one that Lombok generates with @Data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please provide a code snippet if I have to set the value of setOrderNbr to 89898989 without using setOrderNbr(Integer orderNbr), because even I also find it reduntant but without setOrderNbr(Integer orderNbr), I am getting a compile time error as java: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer.

Comment: I feel like you are not reading/hearing what I am saying. JUST CHANGE YOUR METHOD NAME. Like add one character. Change name of `setOrderNbr` to `setOrderNumber` for example.

Comment: I understand what you said and I have changed the method name. But my question is if i want to set the value of OrderNbr using lombok itself without using setOrderNumber, how can I do it. I have updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: like the last paragraph of my answer says if you insist on having a return type you have to write that method yourself. Lombok only generates normal getters/setters, same ones your IDE would have generated, they are not cuszomizable and setters usually dont have return type

Comment: I got you, thank you

Comment: @Rumi See [`@Accessors`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) - you can just ask lombok to do this. SO community: What's the policy when an answer explains context properly, is accepted, but is misleading? Edit an add a note? Just write a comment and let votes sort it out? Add another answer?

Comment: Er, I didn't spend enough time carefully reading the question. Nevermind - no, lombok can't be made to return _the parameter_ (With `@Accessors` you can make lombok return `this`).

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot it worked